# EL expressions are not evaluated in JSP page of JSF

Tags: jsp, jsf, el

My inputname.jsp file

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %> 
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %> 

<html> 
<head> 
<title>enter your name page</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<f:view> 
<h1> 
<h: outputText value="JSF 1.2 Tutorial"/> 
</h1> 
<h:form id="UserEntryForm"> 
<h: outputText value="Enter Your Name:"/> 
<h:inputText value="#{UserBean.userName}" /> 
<h:commandButton action="welcome" value="OK" /> 
</h:form> 
</f:view> 
</body> 
</html> 

My welcome.jsp file 
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %> 
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Welcome</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<f:view> 
<h3> 
<h: outputText value="Welcome" />, 
<hutputText value="#{UserBean.userName}" /> to JSF 1.2 World! 
</h3> 
</f:view> 
</body> 
</html>
```

my web.xml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> 
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC 
"-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" 
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd"> 


<web-app> 

<!-- Faces Servlet --> 
<servlet> 
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name> 
<servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class> 
<load-on-startup> 1 </load-on-startup> 
</servlet> 

<!-- Faces Servlet Mapping --> 
<servlet-mapping> 
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name> 
<url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping> 

</web-app>
```

my faces-config file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> 

<!DOCTYPE faces-config PUBLIC 
"-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JavaServer Faces Config 1.1//EN" 
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-facesconfig_1_1.dtd"> 

<faces-config> 

<navigation-rule> 
<from-view-id>/user/inputname.jsp</from-view-id> 
<navigation-case> 
<from-outcome>welcome</from-outcome> 
<to-view-id>/user/welcome.jsp</to-view-id> 
</navigation-case> 
</navigation-rule> 
<managed-bean> 
<managed-bean-name>UserBean</managed-bean-name> 
<managed-bean-class>net.roseindia.UserNameBean</managed-bean-class> 
<managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope> 
</managed-bean> 

</faces-config>
```

my UserNameBean.java file

```
package net.roseindia; 

public class UserNameBean { 

String userName; 

/** 
* @return User Name 
*/ 
public String getUserName() { 
return userName; 
} 

/** 
* @param User Name 
*/ 
public void setUserName(String name) { 
userName = name; 
} 
}
```

when i open inputname.jsf i get

```
Enter your name: #{UserBean.userName}
```

instead of evaluating userbean.username it is just printing it 
same happens at welcome.jsf 
i get Welcome, #{UserBean.userName} to JSF 1.2 World!

what am i doing wrong 
Please help 
Krishan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using JSF 1.2 on JSP requires a minimum of Servlet 2.5 container because of the changes in EL (EL has been moved from JSF 1.1 to JSP 2.1, which is part of Servlet 2.5). You need to ensure that you're running your JSF 1.2 webapp on a Servlet 2.5 compatible container with a `web.xml` which is declared conform the Servlet 2.5 specification (or better, the maximum whatever your container supports). Your `web.xml` is declared as per Servlet 2.3 which implies a different EL version and hence EL expressions won't be evaluated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <!-- Config here. -->

</web-app>
```

Note that your `faces-config.xml` is incorrectly declared as JSF 1.1. You'd like to redeclare it as JSF 1.2 to fully utilize the JSF 1.2 features.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd"
    version="1.2">

    <!-- Config here. -->

</faces-config>
```

Last, but not least, [Roseindia.net is one of the **WORST** learning resources for Java EE](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2008/06/what-is-it-with-roseindia.html). You should really put that site in your blacklist. Look for a different learning resource. Check the "Resources" section of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Answer (score 0):

Add a correct version to your web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_4.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_4.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4">
```