# JSF not parsing #{} tags

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, tomcat, jsf-1.2

I'm new to JSP/JSF and I've run into a problem with my JSP.

I have several tags that look like this:

```
        <div class="summary">
            <h:outputText escape="false"
                          value="#{FrequencyDistManagedBean.summary}"/>
        </div>
```

But when I view the jsp in my browser, I get this:

```
        <div class="summary">
            #{FrequencyDistManagedBean.summary}
        </div>
```

It parses the h:outputText part, but not the hash/curly braces part. It doesn't mater what I put for the value, it never gets parsed. No errors logged, it just doesn't work. I can even put #{foo.bar} (expecting it to fail with some kind of error) and it makes no difference.

I have the faces servlet mapped to /faces/* (or whatever the default is), and my urls look like: http://www.mysite.com:8080/MyProject/faces/FrequencyDist.jsp  (I'm running Tomcat 6, and using JSF 1.2)

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you post your faces config and web xml as well

Comment: This behavior happens in all your jsps or just in some specific cases?  If is the first case, we could help if you post the web.xml configuration. If not, then just post a [sscce](http://sscce.org/) of the jsp that's giving you problems.

Comment: Agree with Luiggi. Post a small example, then it will be better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [this older SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251401/el-expressions-are-not-evaluated), change your web.xml file's version to 2.5:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">
```

Also set `<faces-config ... version="1.2">`

Googling for `jsf not evaluating el expression` put that link at the top of the search results.

---

Not related to your immediate problem, but you'll run right into this soon:

Verify your use of the controller bean name; I'm referring to the upper-case `F` at the beginning of `FrequencyDistManagedBean`.  By default bean names always begin with lower-case letters.  You should follow the same convention when you explicitly name a bean.

Comment: Here goes:

http://www.guestwho.com/java/web.xml
http://www.guestwho.com/java/faces-config.xml

It's happening with all JSPs, all tags.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: It wouldn't let me post the contents here

Comment: Your links confirm the problem, the solution here should resolve it.

Comment: Thanks, I added version to faces-config, but it won't deploy: Attribute "version" must be declared for element type "faces-config"

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, removed the doctype and replaced the faces-config element with this:

```
<faces-config 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd" 
version="1.2">
```

You rock, thankyou very much for your help!!